# Binomials for getting probability of standard deviation

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

I have the following problem which I am stuck on the second part.

Suppose that $30\%$ of all students who have to buy a text for a particular course want a new copy whereas the other $70\%$ want a used copy. Consider randomly selecting $25$ purchasers.

a. What are the mean value and standard deviation of the number who want a new copy of the book?

b. What is the probability that the number who want new copies is more than two standard deviations away from the mean value?

For part a I did the following:

$\text{mean} = 25(.30) = 7.5$

$\text{standard deviation} = \sqrt{25 \cdot .30 \cdot .70} = 2.291$

For part b however I am stuck. I saw online a similar problem where someone was doing $P(x <1.9) + P(x > 10.1)$ to get their answer, but I have no clue how they came to this conclusion or how to solve $P(x<1.9) + P(x>10.1)$

Answer (score 1):

(b) is asking the following: 
What is the chance that the number of people wanting new copies is either:

- 2 standard deviations above the mean: this means above $7.5+2\cdot 2.291=12.082$, so above or equal to 13 people, in symbols this is $P(x>12.082)=P(x\geq 13)=$
  $=P(x=13)+P(x=14)+\dots+P(x=24)+P(x=25)$,
- or 2 standard deviations below the mean, so below $7.5-2\cdot 2.291=2.918$, so below or equal to 2 people, in symbols: 
  $P(x< 2.918)=P(x\leq 2) = P(x=1)+P(x=2)$.

All together, the probability asked is:
$P(x\leq 2)+P(x\geq 13)= P(x<3)+P(x>12)=$

$P(x=1)+P(x=2)+P(x=13)+P(x=14)+\dots+P(x=24)+P(x=25)$

Now, that's a lot to calculate, it can be a liiittle shortened if you remember that the above sum is equal to:

$1-P(2<x<13)=1-(P(x=3)+\dots +P(x=12))$

But still to me it seems unnecessarily too much to compute in order to learn the binomial distribution... Maybe you have calculators that can compute this kind of sum quickly?

Comment: Maybe CDF(12) - CDF(2)?